# converting mysqli connection object to connection string

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Can we convert mysqli connection object to string connection.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
```

can we convert $mysqli for procedural queries Or it is not possible.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM City ORDER by ID DESC ";

if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $obj->Name;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking; can you clarify the question (and fix the syntax errors in the sample code)?

Comment: Never mind I fixed it. How I can close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mysqli with procedural style because it supports both object-oriented interface the extension and a procedural interface.

[see this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: Thanks yeah just found it.